# Postgres connection with Spring Boot via ssh

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, ssh, proxy

I need to creare a connection to my Postgres database on a Scaleway Instance with Spring Boot for my api service. At the moment I need to pass with my ssh key to connect.

do some one have a guide or a hit to help me? I'm at my second API project so I'm not such an expert :/

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

postgres needs to access the jdbc protocol, not ssh.
see: https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-postgresql/

Comment: Yes it is right. Do you know how set it up during my local development? Must I open the ssh tunnel in any way?